# Calling Activity from Async Task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I am unable to call an activity from async task, i have tried different ways but every time i get a null pointer exception in the log cat.

I have tried this.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



    if(signedin==false)
    {
        Toast.makeText(XMPPClient.context, "authentication failed:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileHome.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

**and this**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


    XMPPClient xmpp = new XMPPClient();
    if(signedin==false)
    {
        Toast.makeText(XMPPClient.context, "authentication failed:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
    }else
        xmpp.startnewactivity();

}
```

**And in XMPPClient.class**

```
public void startnewactivity()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileHome.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

How can i call an activity from async task, actually I want to call activity when async task finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileHome.class);
```

Usually, using `getApplicationContext()` as a `Context` is a very bad idea unless you really know what are you doing. Instead, you should use the `Context` of the `Activity` that you want to start the new from. You can achieve this passing it as a value on `.execute()` or even storing the `Context` you get in the `AsyncTask`'s constructor and store it, so you later can use it in your `onPostExecute()` method.

**---- EDIT ----**

This would be an example:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
   Context context;

   private MyAsyncTask(Context context) { this.context = context; }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(...) {
     super.onPostExecute(result);

     context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ProfileHome.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide me with an example? i have even tried using XMPPClient.this and this.context etc

Comment: And what should i pass in the constructor? Network(getApplicationContext())?

Comment: No, leave it just you have it now. The parameters you pass to the `.execute()` method are received in the `doInBackground()` method, contructor will have the `Context` of the `Activity` that called that `AsyncTask`.