# Executing AsyncTask is not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to execute an AsyncTask to update a textView from an activity when the user taps on a button. The button action is 'openVotar' and the textView to be updated is 'textvaloracionempresa'. When the button is tapped no exception is shown, but anything happens. The URL shown is from a PHP file with a JSON encode function, the output is an array from this type  ["8"].

```
public void openVotar(View view)
    {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxx/cambiarvaloracionempresa.php?id="+idEmpresa
                    );

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
                txtvaloracionempresa.setText((CharSequence) response);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

    }
```

I need your help to update my code. Thank you.

UPDATED QUESTION

Exception thrown:

```
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.Empresas_SingleItemView$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Empresas_SingleItemView.java:151)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.Empresas_SingleItemView$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(Empresas_SingleItemView.java:1)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-18 23:32:47.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1391):     ... 4 more
```

CURRENT CODE:

```
public void openVotar(View view)
{
    Log.i("Response", "Hemos entrado en openVotar: ");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
          new MyAsyncTask().execute();
        else
          new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

@Override
protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Response", "Hemos entrado en asynctask: ");

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
    }
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
    pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
}

public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx/cambiarvaloracionempresa.php?id="+idEmpresa
            );

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
        InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while (true) {
          s = buf.readLine();
          if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0))
            break;
          sb.append(s);
        }

        buf.close();
        ips.close();
        Log.i("Response", "My response is: " + sb.toString());
        txtvaloracionempresa.setText(sb.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does it shows your toast message?

Comment: @hmartinezd, no, it doesn't either.

Comment: It doesn't show up due to the `getApplicationContext()`. Using the Application context is a **bad** idea unless you're completely sure you know what are you doing.

Comment: What is the 151th line of your `Empresas_SingleItemView.java` file?

Comment: @nKn, it is line: postData(params[0]);

Comment: Sure, because in your `.execute()` or `.executeOnExecutor()` you're not passing any parameter, however you're trying to reach it by `params[0]`, which is `null`. Simply replace `.execute(your_string)` and `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, your_string);` respectively.

Comment: @nKn, and which should be my string? I think I have chosen a bad example for AsyncTask... i don't need to pass any param to the task, the url is enough for me.

Comment: If you don't want to pass anything just leave it as in my answer, but then you cannot reference to `params[]` in your `doInBackground()` since you're passing `null`. You just have to specify parameters if you need them, if not, just leave it empty in the `.execute()` and `executeOnExecutor()` calls and don't reference `params[]` in your `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: @nKn, no errors now, but the textview is not updated. I have posted the current at the end of my question, may it is easier to you to detect the problem. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Does this line: `Log.i("Response", "My response is: " + sb.toString());` show anything in `LogCat`, actually the expected value?

Comment: @nKn, the last log message is "Hemos entrado en asynctask: "

Comment: You're not calling `postData()`, it's not processing anything right now.

Comment: @nKn, postData() is not accepted, it shows an error.

Comment: @nKn thank you, I have implemented another AsyncTask method which working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've sent the `HTTP POST` request to the remote server, but you're not processing what it returns. `response` is indeed not the text it returns, but a `HttpResponse`.

You'd need to add something like this:

```
InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s;
while (true) {
  s = buf.readLine();
  if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0))
    break;
  sb.append(s);
}

buf.close();
ips.close();
Log.i("Response", "My response is: " + sb.toString());
```

**---- EDIT ----**

Change your `AsyncTask` execute statement to be like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
  new MyAsyncTask().execute();
else
  new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: I guess the call to MyAsyncTask inside openVotar is not working, any help to call the method?

Comment: Are you running more than one `AsyncTask` at a time in your app?

Comment: I think not. This activity receives the values to be put in the textviews from an intent.

Comment: Put a `Log.d("Hello", "I'm here!")` line in your `doInBackground()` and check whether it shows anything in your `LogCat`.

Comment: I have done it already, and anything is shown on the log cat.

Comment: Weird... try putting that line in your `openVotar()` method. If it shows up, I'll tell you how to modify your `AsyncTask` call.

Comment: OK. thank you. I will tell you if it is shown inside openVotar().

Comment: Check my update, if you want to know more about why it is defined that way: http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/

Comment: Thank you, but there is an error at THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Comment: Solved, I only needed to put min SDK to 11, it was 8

Comment: There is an exception at the asynctask.

Comment: Well, at least now it fires :-) It's probably caused by all the `getApplicationContext()` statements you have, as I pointed in the comment, using this is wrong, you should use the `Context` of the `Activity` that executed the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I guess I should then use another asynctask method, don't you think so? I am new at android coding, could you recommend me how to make it better and easier?

Comment: No, there's no need. A few hours ago I answered a very similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160862/calling-activity-from-async-task/23160935#23160935 `AsyncTask`'s constructor gets the `Context` of the `Activity` that called it, so you simply store it in your `AsyncTask` class and use this context in all your context-based calls.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how to use your answer to the other question in my code...

Comment: Simply implement the constructor (which gets a `Context` as parameter) and save it in your class. Then replace all your `getApplicationContext()` by `context` (which is the `Context` you saved from the constructor). I'm not sure this is the origin of the `NPE` but you should definitely fix it as it might give you some big trouble.

Comment: The only mention to context in my code is for the toast, I think. The NPE origin must be elsewhere. I have removed the toast and the NPE is there.

Comment: Then update your question with the full stacktrace, and point out which line is the one that's giving the `NPE` in your code.

Comment: NPE log posted in the question.